# Client Certificate Authentication with SQUID Forwarding Proxy

Tags: authentication, soap, client-certificates, squid, forward

I have SQUID as https froward proxy in my network. One of my application sends a SAOP request out of the network. The SOAP webservice needs client certificate for auth. I have configured the keystore and truststore for my application. Application is working fine directly without SQUID proxy.

It also works fine with SQUID tunneling (i.e. ssl_bump splice ).

**But** We do not want to use splice. We need SQUID to decrypt SSL traffic and also authenticate and pass the authentication certificate (client certificate) to webservice server.
What are the possible configurations for SQUID for this case ?

For information: SQUID proxy is working fine with HTTP and HTTPS traffic where client certificate for auth is not required. Example "https://www.google.com"

Comment: Hi @learner, 
ever solved this? I'm looking for a solution to add a client-certificate to a http(s)-connection.